# Update Date to Next Month Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing an `UPDATE` statement to Update Table set Column = the last day of next month.

I tried something like this but doesn't seem to work.

```
Update MyTable SET MyColoumn = To_Date(((Month From Current_Timestamp) +1)'-31-2015' , 'MM-DD-YYYY');
```

Comment: That might work if you used `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` But @JustinCave's solution below is better as there might not be a 31st day of the next month (and in this case, there isn't -- February has only 28 days), and that will raise an error with `TO_DATE()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE myTable
   SET myColumn = last_day( add_months( sysdate, 1 ))
```

should work.  `add_months` adds 1 month to the current date.  `last_day` gives you the last day of the month.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be:

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET mycolumn = TRUNC( ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, 2 ), 'MONTH' ) - 1;
```